# R: FME global sensitivity - error "argument parms is missing"

Tags: r, ode

I'm using the FME package to fit a prey-predator model to my data. At the moment I'm just learning and testing the code without fitting anything yet, following this example: http://strimas.com/r/lotka-volterra/

When executing the global sensitivity analyses I get an error and I can't figure out where it comes from.

When I copy paste the example above in my R session, it works. But I can't get my own code to work.
I wrote my function based on another document on FME so the syntax is slightly different.

```
# model function
RMmodel <- function(t, y, parms) {

  #y <- c(N = 30, P = 3)

  derivs <- function(t, y, parms) {
    with(as.list(c(y, parms)), {

      dN <- r * N * (1 - N/K) - a * N * P / (1 + a*h*N)
      dP <- e * a * N * P / (1 + a*h*N) - m * P

      return(list(c(dN, dP)))
    })
  }
  return(ode(y = y, times = t, parms = parms, func = derivs))
}

# input
parameters <- c(r = 0.4, # growth rate prey
                K = 2200, # carrying capacity prey
                a = 0.14, # search rate predator
                h = 1, # handling time
                e = 1.2, # assimilation efficiency predator
                m = 0.2) # mortality rate predator
init <- c(N = 30, P = 3)
times <- seq(0, 120, by=1)

# calculate ODE
RM_result <- RMmodel(t = times, y = init, parms = parameters) # this works

# global sensitivity
par_ranges <- data.frame(min = c(0.18, 1500, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01),
                         max = c(0.25, 3500, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                         row.names = c("r", "K", "a", "h", "e", "m"))

RM_glob_sens <- sensRange(func = RMmodel, parms = parameters,
                          dist = "grid",
                          sensvar = c("N", "P"), parRange = par_ranges,
                          num = 20, t = times)
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
Error in ode(y = y, times = t, parms = parms, func = derivs) : 
  argument "parms" is missing, with no default
```

I tried the following things: adjusted the argument name in the model to "pars" instead of "parms"; added the initial state within the model function; changed the object name of "parameters" to "pars"; changed the order within sensRange(); put the parameters directly in sensRange through c(a = , ...).

I am clearly missing someting but I can't find it for the life of me.
Anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

A requirement of `sensRange()` is that the first argument of `func` is `parms` (see documentation). Change the order of the input arguments in RMmodel and derivs so that parms is the first argument and your code will work.